# Streaming Data

Tags: streaming

I unsuccessfully searched Google for a good definition and understanding of streaming data and its characteristics. My questions are:

1. What is streaming data?
2. How can it be detected?

**Correction:**

"How can it be detected" is not an appropriate question. Instead my question is:

How is it different from buffered data and other data transfer mechanisms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends in what context you mean but basically *streaming data* is analagous to *asynchronous data*.  Take the Web as an example.  The Web (or HTTP specifically) is (basically) a request-response mechanism in that a client makes a request and receives a response (typically a Web page of some kind).

HTTP doesn't natively support the ability for servers to push content to clients.  There are a number of ways this can be faked, including:

- **Polling:** forcing the client to make repeated requests, typically inconspicuously (as far as the client is concerned);
- **Long-lived connections:** this is where the client makes a normal HTTP request but instead of returning immediately the server hangs on to the request until there's something to send back.  When the request times out or a response is sent th eclient sends another request.  In this way you can fake server push;
- **Plug-ins:** Java applets, Flash, Silverlight and others can be used to achieve this.

Anything where the server effectively sends data to the client (rather than the client asking for it)--regardless of the mechanism and whether or not the client is polling for that data--can be characterised as *streaming data*.

With non-HTTP transports (eg vanilla TCP) server push is typically easier (but can still run afoul of firewalls and th elike).  An example of this might be a sharetrading application that receives market information from a provider.  That's streaming data.

How do you detect it?  Bit of a vague question.  I'm not really sure what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1):

When you say streaming data I think of the following, although I'm not sure if this is what you're getting at. To me it's playing a video/audio file while it's downloading. That's what happens when you go to YouTube and watch a video and it starts playing even though you haven't downloaded the whole video yet. But you can see the video downloading - I'm sure you're familiar with the seek bar filling up as the file downloads. It doesn't necessarily have to be a video or audio file but that's the most common.